# How to do paging in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I'd just want to ask how to make a page list, like [First][1][2][3][4][Last].

When the user clicks the page number 4 he will be redirected to page number 4. I need this for my website because scrolling down is a long way and i don't want my visitor to scroll all the way down just to know what's on my website.

[Here's an example](http://i984.photobucket.com/albums/ae329/funnycatster/haha.png).

Comment: what control are you using? GridView, ListView, HTML table etc

Comment: none actually because i don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a GridView control. It has features for paging. Check this links

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx
- [This is also interesting](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-asp-net/)

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyUsers" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20">

</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   gvMyUsers.DataSource = GetUsersFromDatabase(); //e.g. DataTable, DataReader, List<MyUser>, Any IEnumerable
   gvMyUsers.DataBind();
}
```

That gives you an idea of what to expect.

You can do more readups and googling on GridView, Paging etc